# calling command line from .NET application

Tags: c#, .net, command-line

I want to call from a c# application a command line starting from it an application and retrieve the stat from it.

I did this but something is missing:

```
ProcessStartInfo psf = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe", "/C time");
psf.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
psf.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
psf.UseShellExecute = false;
psf.CreateNoWindow = true;
Process p = Process.Start(psf);
StreamReader sr = p.StandardOutput;
p.WaitForExit();
```

What is wrong ?

Comment: `cmd/c Time` expects user input. It won't close unless you provide some input to it. In your case, you are hiding the command window. That makes it look like an input is pending in hidden window. 
what do you want the code to do?

Comment: I don't want to change the time only getting it from this application

Comment: Could you not use `DateTime.Now`?

Comment: In that case, use `cmd /c time /t` as @Lukas has said.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try passing "/c time /t" instead of "/c time".

Comment: Yes i got the data. What did /t did ? How can I get also the miliseconds ?

Comment: As others stated above, without /t, the command asks for input. But I don't think the "time" command supports miliseconds. This has also been stated before, but why not simply use DateTime.Now instead?

Comment: I need to check from differences between this option and the DateTime object and another thing. Thanks

Comment: So what about using "echo %time%" instead of "/c time /t"? Can you use that instead?

Comment: Create a process and to the command line to send this arguments ?

Comment: Yes, try new ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe", "/C echo %time%") - this produces output like "10:32:41,18", which is nearly what you need.

Answer (score 1):

To get the system time I would recommend you using the [DateTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.aspx) structure:

```
string time = DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm:ss.fff");
Console.WriteLine(time);
```

Comment: I need to use shell and time and not the datewtime object